# Not able to set the options of the dropdown to the fields returned by the api in json format

Tags: c#, json, angular, api, parsing

I am calling a WCF service from my angular 6 code and the data that is returned is in JSON. But when I am accepting the returned data it is throwing some error like :

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[{"Company_Prefix":"SCL","Company_Name":"Smart Chip Private Limited","Company_Code":"SCL"},{"Company_Prefix":"SYS","Company_Name":"Syscom Corporation Private Limited","Company_Code":"SYS"},{"Company_Prefix":"V-SCL","Company_Name":"Vihaan Infrasystems India Limited","Company_Code":"V-SCL"},{"Company_Prefix":"OT","Company_Name":"OT Morpho","Company_Code":"OT"}]' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

I have tried MAP and It doesn't help.

**TS file:**

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
import { CompanyModel } from './../Models/app.CompanyModel';
import { CommonService } from './../../Shared/Common.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CreateEmployeeModel } from '../Models/app.create-EmployeeModel';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-employee',
  templateUrl: './create-employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-employee.component.css',
  '../../Content/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css']
})
export class CreateEmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

  private _employeeModel : CreateEmployeeModel;
  UserName:string = sessionStorage.getItem('UserName');
  companies: CompanyModel[];
  departments: string[];
  errorMessage: any;

  constructor(private _CommonService:CommonService) {  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    debugger;
    this._employeeModel = new CreateEmployeeModel();
    this._employeeModel.UserName=this.UserName;

    this._CommonService.BindCompany(this._employeeModel)
    .subscribe(data => 
      {
        debugger;
        this.companies=data;
      },
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);

    // this._CommonService.BindDepartment(this._employeeModel).subscribe(data=>this.departments=data);
  }

**Service:**
import { CompanyModel } from './../HR/Models/app.CompanyModel';
import { CreateEmployeeModel } from './../HR/Models/app.create-EmployeeModel';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CommonService {
  private _parse;
  private _response;
  private data: any;
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient, private _Route: Router) {  }

  private api='http://localhost:10704/CommonService.svc';

  BindCompany(EmployeeModel: CreateEmployeeModel): Observable<CompanyModel[]>
  {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    debugger;
    return this._http.get<CompanyModel[]>( this.api+'/BindCompany/' + EmployeeModel.UserName, { headers: headers } )
    .pipe(tap(data=>{
      debugger;
      // this._parse=JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(data);
        if(data!=null)
        {
          return (data);
        }
        else
        {
          return null;
        }
    }),
    catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

**JSON DATA THAT API RETURNS:**
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
[{"Company_Prefix":"XXX",
"Company_Name":"XXX Private Limited",
"Company_Code":"XXX"},
{"Company_Prefix":"XXX",
"Company_Name":"XXX Corporation Private Limited",
"Company_Code":"XXX"},
{"Company_Prefix":"V-XXX",
"Company_Name":"XXX Infrasystems India Limited",
"Company_Code":"V-XXX"},
{"Company_Prefix":"XXX",
"Company_Name":"OT XXX",
"Company_Code":"XXX"}]
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're not parsing the response. Make amend to your service while referring to the code below.

```
return this._http.get<CompanyModel[]>( this.api+'/BindCompany/' + EmployeeModel.UserName, { headers: headers } )
.pipe(tap(data=>{
    if(data!=null)
    {
      return JSON.parse(data);
    }
    else
    {
      return null;
    }
}),
catchError(this.handleError)
);
```